# How to determine database vendor?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I need to implement different logic for different databases (because DB2 and Mssql does not support regexp). How can I determine database vendor? (config file is not an option)
I use Java.

Comment: Abstract away from DBMS detail by using an ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: If you know the driver class that the app is using for the connection, you can know the vendor.

Comment: Hope [This will][1] help you to resolve the issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223159/can-you-determine-which-database-vendor-is-used-from-a-sqlexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName--) as this is implemented by driver vendors.It will give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DbDictionaryFactory. calculateDBDictionary(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa-jdbc/2.0.0-beta/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/DBDictionaryFactory.java#DBDictionaryFactory.calculateDBDictionary%28org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfiguration%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) from open-jpa.

This utility attempts to determine the database by url and driver class and will return an appropriate DBDictionary (eg OracleDictionary or MySQLDictionary).